# Is there a way to access headers & cookies in Service?

Tags: feathersjs

I have a feathersjs style ToDo service configured in node and it needs to make REST call to a a JAVA bases API end point. It needs to pass cookies and header info that came from the web. However in the service find method I get params which do not have any of the info I need.

I have tried to look into implementing hooks but the context object doesn't seem to have such info as well.

```
module.exports = class ToDo {
  constructor() { }
  find(params) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      ...run some business logic
      const reqConfig = { path: path, header:, cookies:)

      restService.request(reqConfig).then(() {//business logic});
  }
};
```

restService is a internal utility which requires config object with BE . API path, headers & cookies.

I expect to be able to pass headers & cookies. So far I have not found a way.

Answer (score 1):

From [the FAQ](https://docs.feathersjs.com/faq/readme.html#how-do-i-access-the-request-object-in-hooks-or-services):

> If you still need something from the request object (for example, the requesting IP address) you can simply tack it on to the `req.feathers` object [as described here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/express.html#params):

```
  app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    req.feathers.fromMiddleware = 'Hello world';
    next();
  });
```

Comment: This worked but only for REST calls, how can I achieve the same for Socket?

Comment: This is documented in the same section of the [Socket.io transport documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/socketio.html#params).

Comment: That did work, however I need to make a async call to add some info to feathers object.

Is there a way either to delay the request over primus soket until I have completed async operation either on server or the client?

Comment: Here is my changes:
`primus.use((req, res) => {
      const userToken = req.userToken; //there is more code I am just pasting part 
      tokenService.getTokenData(userToken, function(error, session) {
        if (!error) {
          const headers = _.get(req, 'headers');
          req.feathers.headers = headers;
          req.feathers.session = session;
        }
      });
    });
`

Comment: So this was the solution. `primus.use((req, res, next) => { .... next()}`